# How to write constructor with composition in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

can you help me with composition in C++ please?
I have class User, who contains:
User.h

```
class User
{
public:
    std::string getName();
    void changeName(std::string nName);
    std::string getGroup();
    void changeGroup(std::string nGroup);

    User(std::string nName, std::string nGroup);
    ~User(void);
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string group;
};
```

Now I define in class Honeypot:

Honeypot.h:

```
class Honeypot
{
public:
    User us;
```

I have constructor:

```
Honeypot (std::string name, std::string ip, int numberOfInterfaces, std::string os);
```

in Honeypot.cpp:

```
Honeypot::Honeypot(std::string name, std::string ip, int numberOfInterfaces, std::string os):us(nName, nGroup){
    this->name = name;
    this->ip = ip;
    this-> numberOfInterfaces = numberOfInterfaces; 
    this->os = os;
}
```

But this syntax is not correct. Errors are:

```
IntelliSense: expected a ')', 'nGroup' : undeclared identifier  and more on line :us(nName, nGroup){...
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: you didn't define `nGroup` or `nName` as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nName and nGroup need to be parameters of the Honeypot constructor; as the compiler indicates, they're undeclared.

```
Honeypot::Honeypot(std::string name, std::string ip, 
                   int numberOfInterfaces, std::string os, 
                   std::string userName, std::string userGroup) 
    : us(userName, userGroup)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->ip = ip;
    this->numberOfInterfaces = numberOfInterfaces; 
    this->os = os;
}
```